# How can I send log from fluentd to influxDB?

Tags: ruby, parsing, fluentd

I'm in trouble with the parser of Fluentd not working.
I don't know where the hell the problem is.

1. fluentd.conf

```
<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_app_logs
  path /tmp/log/test/*.log
  pos_file /var/log/app.log.pos
  tag logging.app
  refresh_interval 1
  read_from_head true
  <parse>
    @type regexp
    expression /^(?<time>.+?)\t(?<logname>.+?)\t(?<log>.+?)$/
    time_key time
    time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z
  </parse>
</source>

<match logging.app>
  @type stdout
  @type copy
  <store ignore_error>
    @type file
    path /tmp/log/influx
  </store>
  <store>                                                                                  
    @type influxdb
    host 20.10.222.22
    port 8086
    user test
    password test123
    use_ssl false
    dbname test
    measurement test_measurement
    time_precision s
    auto_tags true
    flush_interval 10
    verify_ssl false
    sequence_tag _seq
  </store>
</match>
```

2. /tmp/log/test/buffer.*.log

```
...

2023-02-06T08:09:46+00:00   kubernetes.var.log.containers.app-test-app-test-space-fb5ffca1ec-0_cf-workloads_opi-05942675f9f0dd17039304733f228e7abd6ebdfd91609baf1a7afefaeb33ced8.log    {"stream":"stdout","log":"Console output from test-node-app","docker":{"container_id":"05942675f9f0dd17039304733f228e7abd6ebdfd91609baf1a7afefaeb33ced8"},"kubernetes":{"container_name":"opi","namespace_name":"cf-workloads","pod_name":"app-test-app-test-space-fb5ffca1ec-0","pod_id":"f4f2592e-ed57-4375-aff7-40c7b214abe0","host":"ap-joy-sidecar-5","labels":{"controller-revision-hash":"app-test-app-test-space-fb5ffca1ec-5bb7dc5769","cloudfoundry_org/app_guid":"8fc07280-506c-49b2-ab00-a97222fcf0a5","cloudfoundry_org/guid":"8fc07280-506c-49b2-ab00-a97222fcf0a5","cloudfoundry_org/org_guid":"fdf0a222-33a4-46fd-a7f9-7955b9ea862c","cloudfoundry_org/org_name":"system","cloudfoundry_org/process_type":"web","cloudfoundry_org/source_type":"APP","cloudfoundry_org/space_guid":"f1b70a4b-7581-4214-b128-2f1597f7789d","cloudfoundry_org/space_name":"app-test-space","cloudfoundry_org/version":"ebfde654-e73c-48da-b55b-42a37a6ba139","security_istio_io/tlsMode":"istio","service_istio_io/canonical-name":"app-test-app-test-space-fb5ffca1ec","service_istio_io/canonical-revision":"latest","statefulset_kubernetes_io/pod-name":"app-test-app-test-space-fb5ffca1ec-0"}},"app_id":"8fc07280-506c-49b2-ab00-a97222fcf0a5","instance_id":"f4f2592e-ed57-4375-aff7-40c7b214abe0","structured_data":"[tags@47450 source_type=\"APP/PROC/WEB\"]"}
...
```

I think `\t` exists between time, logname, and log.

I tried the following methods.

## What I tried

### 1. fluentd.conf

#### json

```
<parse>
  @type json
  time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z
</parse>
```

#### tsv

```
<parse>
  @type tsv
  keys time,logname,logs
  time_key time
  time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z
</parse>
```

#### none

```
<parse>
  @type none
</parse>
```

### 2. result

Log files did not exist for all.
There is no output when using stdout parser except json parser.

## What I want

I want the parser to work normally and to send data to influxdb.
Please help me...

Comment: Please add the fluentd startup logs to your question. There are two `@type` configurations in your match section i.e. `stdout` and `copy`. Is that a typo? In the posted log, after the timestamp, there are three spaces; and, before JSON log there are four. Those are not tabs, not at least in that log. Please verify this as well.

Comment: Here's an example: https://regex101.com/r/Y93Mq2/1 with `/^(?<time>.+?)\s+(?<logname>.+?)\s+(?<log>.+?)$/`.